# Semantic check of expression with ANTLR 4

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

With a (simplified) grammar that recognizes classes of the form

```
classDeclaration
    : Class className=Identifier
      ( Extends parentClassIdentifier=PackageIdentifier )?
      ( classSpecifier )*
      Semicolon
    ;
classSpecifier
    : ( Abstract | Final )
    | /* ... */
    ;
```

one could easily create a class and make it both abstract and final

```
class MyContradiction abstract final;
```

In my current grammar I have some of these keywords which don't make sense when combined. How do I check for those combinations that don't make sense. **Should I modify my grammar to prevent this by including horrible loops and checks or should I check in code using listener or visitors which flags are set and which ones do not make sense?**

Comment: Expanded a bit my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that checking for these wrong combinations in code is better because you have a chance to give user a better error message than something like 'syntax error'.

To clarify, the code which checks these kind of semantic constraints, catches the wrong combinations of keywords, etc., should be in code, but in the code of parser's semantic actions. This is the best place for it. So you have this in the same file as the grammar, but you don't make the grammar itself more complicated.

I've seen parsers where the semantic actions contained code which was evaluating expressions of the language being parsed and more, basically some people embed interpreters of the parsed language in the grammar file. This is wrong. The parser should produce AST and that's it. But, again, it is best to do things like checking wrong combination of keywords in semantic actions in the grammar file, I believe. Someone studying your grammar will not see these very syntax related things, also you may simply forget to do these checks after parsing is completed. And, after all, returning from your parser an AST of a text which is illegal for your grammar is a bit dodgy, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer - now it should be clear. Writing `class Foo abstract final;` is syntactically correct, such that my grammar shouldn't complain and only during the execution of the parser it makes sense to do so.